# Adding youtube subscribe button to my code

Tags: html, youtube

I am coding in HTML and i want to add the subscribe button into my code for a certain channel, how?  i have tried multiple ways. PLease help if you need more information please just say so.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just add your channel name in the div.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="UEDCaamflyer" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
```

For example my channel

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button)

Make sure you have included this JS file:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```